# ImportError No module named request

Tags: python, django, opencv

`C:\Users\james\Desktop\FaceRecognitionAPI-master\FaceRecognitionAPI-master>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...`

`Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x037446B0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\james\Desktop\FaceRecognitionAPI-master\FaceRecognitionAPI-master\facerec\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from api import views
  File "C:\Users\james\Desktop\FaceRecognitionAPI-master\FaceRecognitionAPI-master\api\views.py", line 9, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urllib.requests in Python 2 does not exist, [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html) module was split in Python 3 and renamed

> The urllib module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to
>   urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will
>   automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.
>   Also note that the urllib.request.urlopen() function in Python 3 is
>   equivalent to urllib2.urlopen() and that urllib.urlopen() has been
>   removed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a `urllib.request` in Python 2, only 3.